# How do I parse nested JSON?

Tags: json, parsing, delphi, delphi-2010

How do I parse this JSON?

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "animals": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "pig",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to parse the JSON by:

```pascal
jsonobject := TJsonObject.ParseJSONValue(RestResponse.Content) as TJsonObject;
```

Then I get `"animals":[{"id" ...` . Now here it gets complicated, how do I parse further to get `id` and `name`? Parse JSON further or parse JSON array? Can someone help me (*with example code*), please?

Comment: Its Delphi code

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Please be more specific. The whole JSON has already been parsed (BTW, look at `RestResponse.JsonValue` so you don't have to call `ParseJSONValue`), all you have to do is iterate through the result. `TJSONObject` has methods for accessing individual fields. You know `"result"` is an array (`TJSONArray`) of objects (`TJSONObject`), which contain another array of objects. You seem to already know how to reach the `"animals"` field from the `"results"` array. So what's stopping you from reaching the `"name"`/`"id"` fields from the `"animals"` array?

Comment: Can you give me the code please? No, there is a problem. If I try to reach inside Animals it shows error. Result too complicated or something like this or typecast error or simple runtime error. I can't get inside animal array.

Comment: Access violation error.

Comment: Here:    jo := TJsonObject.Create;
   jo1 := TJsonObject.Create;

   strJson := TJson.Format(RestResponse1.JSONValue);

   jo := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(strJson) as TJsonObject;
   ja := jo.GetValue('result') as TJSONArray;

   jo1 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TJson.Format(ja)) as TJsonObject;
   jaa := jo.GetValue('animals') as TJSONArray;  - HERE WILL THROW TYPECAST ERROR
   showmessage(jaa.ToString);

Comment: Actually here is the typecast error when I try to parse animals object - the TJson.Format(ja) is typasted wrong. jo1 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TJson.Format(ja)) as TJsonObject; How to do it right and read the pairs?

Comment: First off, that code is leaking memory. Second, you don't need all of those Format() and ParseJSONValue() calls, only the parse of the RestResponse.Content (and even that one, you can get rid of if you use RestResponse.JsonValue instead). Once you have the initial TJSONArray, simply iterate its items in a loop, casting each one to TJsonObject

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON string contain an array embedded in another array. You can get the value of the first array ("result") and iterate its elements. For each element you have an array of "animals" that you can iterate to get "id" and "name".

Simple code to do that :

```
const
    JSONStr2 =
'{' +
   '"result": [' +
     '{' +
       '"animals": [' +
         '{"id": 1, "name": "pig"},' +
         '{"id": 2, "name": "rabit"}' +
       ']' +
     '}' +
   ']' +
 '}';

 procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    JSONValue      : TJSONValue;
    JSONResult     : TJSONArray;
    JSONResultItem : TJSONValue;
    JSONAnimals    : TJSONArray;
    JSONAnimalItem : TJSONValue;
begin
    JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONStr);
    if not Assigned(JSONValue) then begin
        ShowMessage('JSON syntax error');
        Exit;
    end;
    try
        JSONResult := JSONValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('result');
        for JSONResultItem in JSONResult do begin
            JSonAnimals := JSONResultItem.GetValue<TJSONArray>('animals');
            for JSONAnimalItem in JSONAnimals do begin
                Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s = %s',
                                       [JSONAnimalItem.GetValue<String>('id'),
                                        JSONAnimalItem.GetValue<String>('name')]));
            end;
        end;
    finally
        JSONValue.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! love your ICS components!

Comment: Almost perfect except on JSONAnimalItem.GetValue<String>('id'), I get F2084 Internal Error: AV09B46626-R00000148-0

Comment: But we are making progress, now I get the animals array right. only some error parsing the animal array...

Comment: Actually its all right! If I do it on showmessage I get exactly the right value. Maybe Memo1 problem. Anyway it works. Thanks